# WatiN Test Recorder: How to get the compiled code in C# from the steps the recorder records

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automation, automated-tests, watin

I am using Watin Test Recorder for the first time, have recorded test like opening IE, giving the URL as http://www.google.com and then entering something in the text box of Google

Is there any way I can get the C# equivalent code for the same steps in Watin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using V2.0 of the recorder, you should just be able to copy the C# code to 
the clipboard and do as you please from there.

Watch this:  http://www.viewletcentral.com/vc/viewlet/684114871/.
About half way through the copy-to-clipboard is shown.

Comment: Doing the same should generate the code at which location and how can we run it...plz suggest any solution